# How does this initialization for char array in C++ work?

Tags: c++

I'm quite new to C++ and I saw this way of initialization for char array which I never learn before. I wanted to know how does the code below work compared to assignment like
`char tmp[] = {'a','b','c',...};`

```
const char charset[] = 
                        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" 
                        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYS" 
                        "0123456789";
```

Comment: This is an initialization.

Comment: If there is a `'\0'` or `0` at the end of `{'a','b','c',...}`, they do the same thing. A string literal like `"hello"` has an implied 0-terminator at the end, which you explicitly have to write as an element.

Comment: Note that `"abc" "def"` is the same as `"abcdef"`. Splitting that initializer into three lines is about readability, not about its content. It could have been written `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYS0123456789"`.

Answer (score -1):

String literals are stored somewhere in your executable and the compiler knows the address in which they is stored. By assigning a string literal to a char* pointer, the address of the memory location in which the literal is stored is copied to the variable. On the other hand, initializing an array with a string literal copies the string into the array while setting the leftover elements of the array to zero.

Note that string literals are stored with a trailing zero byte automatically. The only difference between this method and the curly braces initialization is the addition of trailing zero by the compiler.

Comment: “*By assigning a string literal to an array (or a char\*) the address of the memory location in which the literal is stored is copied to the variable.*” - that is only true when assigning a string literal to a pointer. When initializing an array with a string literal, the *content* of the string literal is copied into the elements of the array, and any unfilled elements are initialized to zeros.